# Access qgis.explodelines in Python (outside QGIS)

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, explode

I want to access the explodelines function in Python outside of QGIS from a standalone script.

```
import sip
for api in ["QDate", "QDateTime", "QString", "QTextStream", "QTime", "QUrl", "QVariant"]:
    sip.setapi(api, 2)


import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins')

from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

# Run the algorithm
layerInput = QgsVectorLayer("files/centre/colour/streets.shp", 'test', 'ogr')
general.runalg('qgis:explodelines', layerInput, 'temp.shp')

# Exit applications
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

**EDIT:**

The result of the algorithm is: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'**
I used various shapefiles but none of them worked.

Comment: Did you try using the **full path** to the shapefile? (e.g. `C:/someDirectory/files/centre/colour/streets.shp`. What happens if you type `print layerInput`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but no change.

**<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x00000000144D68C8>**

Comment: Sorry, I meant using the full path as the input parameter: `general.runalg('qgis:explodelines', 'C:/someDirectory/files/centre/colour/streets.shp', 'temp.shp')`

Comment: No, it don't change anything.. The error: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'** appears

Comment: There could be errors in your shapefile. Try loading the shapefile into QGIS and running the **Check validity** tool.

Comment: Hey @Joseph .. I test various shapefiles, but none of them worked... Did You test my algorithm?
I use the algorithm from this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/accessing-processing-with-python but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Perhaps you actually don't need the first 3 lines of your script, as you can see in the thread you mentioned.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo: This is right, but the error stays...Can You help me please (Processing-version: 2.12.99)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following link the problem with the processing framework has been solved:
[Link 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204321/qgis-2-16-processing-runalg-fails-when-run-outside-of-qgis-in-a-custom-applicat)

--> Just change two lines in AlgorithmExecutor.py like [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/df2ca2e60798315d816966f25aa024b93835f776).